# How does __TransparentProxy work?

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy

When using WCF, we can define a service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    int MyOperation(int x);
}
```

Assume I open a servicehost at `www.example.com/MyService`, then one way to use this service from my client is

```
IMyService service =
    new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(new BasicHttpBinding(),
        new EndpointAddress("www.example.com/MyService")).CreateChannel();
int result = service.MyOperation(10);
```

So somehow, `service` implements `IMyService`, although that was never done explicitly. If I debug these lines, I can see that `service` is an instance of [`__TransparentProxy`](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Dotnetfx_Vista_SP2/Dotnetfx_Vista_SP2/8@0@50727@4016/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/NetFxQFE/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Runtime/Remoting/__TransparentProxy@cs/1/__TransparentProxy@cs). As you can see from the source code, the comments in that class say

> Transparent proxy **magically** creates a message that represents a call on it and delegates to the Real proxy to do the real remoting work.

To me this is indeed 'magic', but I guess there must be a logical explanation.

---

The pattern here can be very useful. What I would like is some class like `Magic` below (the syntax is incorrect, I know, otherwise I wouldn't need to ask). For the sake of argument, let's say I want this class to print the name of the method called.

```
public class Magic<T> : T {
    // don't know what to do here
}
```

Such that I would be able to call

```
IMyService service = new Magic<IMyService>();
service.MyOperation(10);
```

And this would print:

```
MyOperation
```

Is something like this possible? (It should be, since `__TransparentProxy` does something similar.) And if so, how would this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few articles on Codeplex that try to do something similar to what WCF does under the covers:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43598/Emit-Proxy
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5511/Dynamic-Proxy-Creation-Using-C-Emit

The `System.Reflection.Emit` namespace is the underlying key, which can be used to dynamically create .NET assemblies and types in code.

Comment: Interesting! I'll have a look at those projects to see if they can provide the functionality I need :)

Answer (score 0):

Any one else running across this answer might want to look at Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) in general

And possibly PostSharp specifically: https://www.postsharp.net/aop.net